# pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen ERROR "pyscreeze.PyScreezeException: The Pillow package is required to use this function"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

I am running into an issue and I am not sure what is causing it.

The code I am running is as follows:

```
gs_empty_search_btn_x, gs_empty_search_btn_y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('pictures/shopping/search_bar_empty.png',
                                                                              confidence=.8)
print(gs_empty_search_btn_x)
```

For reference:

- My OS is Windows
- I am using PyCharm Community 2022.2.1
- I have PIL (9.2.0) installed
- PyAutoGui (0.9.53) installed

I ran `pip install Pillow` & `pip install --upgrade  Pillow`" already and got `"Requirement already satisfied"` for both

I tried `File -> Settings -> Project name -> Python Interpreter -> + -> Type pyautogui -> Install Package`

I tried `Python Packages > Pillow > Uninstalled Pillow > Re-Installed Pillow` , still got the same error.

I added `import PIL` and Installed `Pillow` manually, still not working

I did `pip freeze` and got `Pillow ==9.2.0`

Nothing I am doing is working. Please help!

Comment: you may have common problem: you have two Pythons and you install module in one Python but you run code with other Python. But Pythons don't share modules. In code runs `print( sys.executable )` to get `/full/path/to/python` and later in run `/full/path/to/python -m pip install pillow` to install module for this Python.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Had to delete everything and start over and delete a few packages that relied on other Python versions

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).